# XSLT -- Counting attributes within an element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML similar to

```
<BOXHEAD>
  <COLHEAD H="1">Item</COLHEAD>
  <COLHEAD H="2">Cost</COLHEAD>
  <COLHEAD H="3">Direct</COLHEAD>
  <COLHEAD H="3">In-Direct</COLHEAD>
  <COLHEAD H="2">Revenue</COLHEAD>
  <COLHEAD H="3">1989</COLHEAD>
  <COLHEAD H="3">1990</COLHEAD>
</BOXHEAD>
```

I have tried something similar to this to translate to an HTML COLSPAN:

```
<xsl:if test="@H=2">
    <xsl:variable name="descendants" select="following-sibling::COLHEAD[@H = 3]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="number_of_columns_under_this" select="count($descendants)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$number_of_columns_under_this &gt; 1">
        <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
            <xsl:value-of select="$number_of_columns_under_this"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

Desired result: "cost" column should come out to `colspan="2"` but of course the `count()` picks up all four of the `@H="3"` in the block. I'm trying to turn that ancient SGML into an HTML table. The desired out put is similar to this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="2">Item</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">Cost</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">Revenue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Direct</td>
    <td>In-Direct</td>
    <td>1989</td>
    <td>1990</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Calculating the rowspan and colspan is proving to be difficult for me.

Comment: Can you post the desired output XML for that sample input?

Comment: The requirement .. seems like I understand but am not quiet sure.. What I understand is .. since you are using following-sibling it will return `4` when you encounter `<COLHEAD H="2">Cost</COLHEAD>` and it returns `2` when you encounter `<COLHEAD H="2">Revenue</COLHEAD>`

Comment: What you are expecting it to return **is the count of consecutive** `COLHEAD` elements(having attribute H="3") following to current-node.. is that right??

Comment: @InfantPro... I edited the original question and added the desired output.

Comment: this question has been answered isn't it?? Is it not satisfactory??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a trick like this

```
<xsl:variable name="descendants"
    select="following-sibling::COLHEAD[@H = 3]
       [generate-id((preceding-sibling::COLHEAD[@H=2])[last()])
         = generate-id(current())]"/>
```

This selects all `COLHEAD[@H=3]` elements whose *nearest* preceding-sibling `@H=2` is the one we're currently looking at.

Comment: Wow. I'll try that. Right now I'm still trying to understand it.

Comment: @Paulb `generate-id` is a very useful function, it allows you to check whether two expressions select the _same node_ (as opposed to just nodes that have the same string value).  So what I'm doing here is: for each `@H=3` COLHEAD find all its preceding-sibling `@H=2` elements, choose the one of those that is latest in document order, and check whether it's the same node as the `@H=2` that we started from (using `current()` to get the context node from outside the `[]`)

Comment: Thank you Ian. Worked perfectly.. and your explanation helped me learn something new. The generate-id will be useful to me in other places as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in XSLT 2.0 you should probably use positional grouping for this, something like `<xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="[@H='2']>`. But without knowing exactly what output you want, it's hard to offer you more detail.

Comment: The answer yesterday worked for a couple use-cases, then fell apart. So maybe I will look into XSLT 2.0 for-each-group. I've clarified my original question by adding a desired output. Thank you.